# Will the airport's X-ray scanner damage my Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm considering bringing my Xbox 360 on a trip I'm taking, but I'm worried that the airport security scanner will damage the hard drive inside. Is this a valid concern?

Comment: Make sure it's well packaged with plenty of bubblewrap and/or foam to protect against shocks.

Comment: The Xbox is made of Xrays! :D

Comment: I've taken mine as carry on before, it didn't hurt it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware in general, should be asked on superuser.com instead.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You'll be fine. Millions of passengers have no problem with laptops brought through airport security. Your XBox will be fine.

Here's a quote from [About.com](http://mobileoffice.about.com/od/businesstravelersadvice/tp/airportsafety.htm):

> Letting your laptop go through the
>   x-ray equipment will not harm your
>   laptop. The magnetic field which is
>   generated is not enough to cause harm
>   to your hard drive or cause damage to
>   your data. Metal detectors on the
>   other hand, can cause damage and
>   request politely that Security/Customs
>   do not use the metal detector but do a
>   hand check instead.

Comment: Nice bonus about the metal detector info.  Thanks!

Comment: Some good info in this answer.